# What is the difference between the project manager and business analyst role?

Tags: roles, business-analyst

I am bit confused between the role of project manager and business analyst. What is the basic difference between the two?

Comment: It would be nice if you can list down the confusion you have between the roles (which you have also mentioned in your question). Thanks.

Comment: Currently as it stands, your question is a bit broad and open-ended.

Comment: Good answer by DPH, thank you for your teachings!

Comment: There is nothing open ended about this @Aziz.  How could the OP possibly list their confusion?  That is absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're just different roles.

A PM is responsible for guiding the project to successful completion.

A Business Analyst is typically responsible for elaborating the solution from concept to detailed requirements.

There can be conflict between the two roles, also. In some organizations, there is a combined PM/BA role. I tend to recommend against them, because there is often a conflict of interests in how the project should be managed.

PM-oriented people tend to want to deliver the project on-time, on-budget, etc. BA-oriented people often tend to favor extending the project to improve the delivered product.